# android autobahn : Sending byte array from android receive as ascci characters in python server

Tags: android, autobahn

I am sending byte array using autobahn android to the server and the server is using python language.The server supports to get byte array but it appears as ascci characters. Thank for your help in advance

Comment: Are there any questions?

Comment: I would like to know what is the problem of the server is getting string instead of binary even though the client send binary packet.

Comment: You did not show that you send a binary packet and you also did not show how you receive.